# Logarithmic regression with individual errors

Tags: regression, lognormal-distribution

If I have a dataset of $N$ pairs ($x_i$,$y_i$) where each $y_i$ has an individual error $\sigma_{y_i}$, I can incorporate this into regression by using the inverse of this as weights.

If I now do logarithmic regression $\ln y_i = b_0 + b_1\,\ln x_i + \epsilon_i$, how do I incorporate now the errors? Are the weights just plain the same as in the linear case or do I have to convert them using the lognormal distribution: $Var = \mathrm{e}^{2\mu+\sigma^{2}}(\mathrm{e}^{\sigma^{2}}-1)$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variance of $y_i$ is $\sigma_i^2,$ then, by the [delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method), the variance of $\log(y_i)$ is approximately $\sigma_i^2 / y_i^2 .$ So if you're doing [weighted least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#Weighted_least_squares) using inverse-variance weights, instead of weighting by $1/\sigma_i^2 ,$ you need to weight by $y_i^2 / \sigma_i^2 .$

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. I was searching for nearly a week for a definitive answer and didn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

It is good to remember what is the purpose of the weighting. Suppose we have linear regression

\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta}+\mathbf{\varepsilon}
\end{align}

In this case $\sigma_{y_i}=\sigma_{\varepsilon_i}=\sigma_i$ and we can write that

$$\Omega=E(\varepsilon\varepsilon')=diag(\sigma_i)$$

Now weighted regression with weights inverse to $\sigma_i$ is [generalised least squares estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) with $\Omega$. Generalised least squares estimates are best linear unbiased estimates if variance of errors is $\Omega$.

So you need to know the variance of errors, not the $y$. If you fit logarithmic regression and you know that $y$ is log normal, you need to weight with the variance of $\log y$, which in your case will correspond to variance of $\epsilon$. Then your weighted least squares estimates will be best linear unbiased estimates, and you will retain the same property as in linear case.

Comment: I'm no statistician but a physicist trying to analyse some data, so thank you for this nice explanation.